# how to receive the putExtra image?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to pass an `ImageView` between 2 activities using `putExtra`.
Sending the `ImageView` is ok I guess, but idk how can I receive it on the other activity.

My code - 
**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostsAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

final String image_data = list_post.get(position).getImage_url();
holder.setIntroIMG(image_data);


holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent goToFullPost = new Intent(context, FullPostActivity.class);
        goToFullPost.putExtra("image_url", image_data);
        context.startActivity(goToFullPost);

    }
});
```

}

Other activity -

I'm receiving the Image as the following -

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_post);

    String setMainImage = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Send

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FullPostActivity.class);
Bitmap bitmap; 
ByteArrayOutputStream btArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, btArrayOutputStream );
intent.putExtra("image", btArrayOutputStream .toByteArray());
startActivity(intent);
```

Receive

```
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(      getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image"),0,getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image").length);        
imgView .setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I cannot use the file path because the image is stored on Firebase.. my app is like - image uplpaded by someone, it stores at Firebase, then using the image for a cardview recyclerview and then once the exact cardview is clicked, the image should retrieve to the new activity with the text.

Comment: In this case, you need to retrieve an image from firebase, by some unique id. You can create a unique key for the image in Firebase, pass it inside your intent and retrieve it later from Firebase by that key. You can use the code that I posted to send an image inside the intent. If it works.please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Yeah I tried to make that work out, but I never succeed to retrieve the key of an image and send it to the other activity.. I tried looking everywhere online for it, but nothing.

Comment: When I write rootRef, it gives me an error like it doesn't need to be written at all.. Can you just show me how can I do that on my code?

Comment: Adding and retrieving image to Firebase is a completely different question. Post the code ,where you add image to firebase,than I'll be able to help. If you want to pass it in the intent, use the code I have posted already: "Send" and "Receive"

Comment: Hey, so I tried your code and it partly worked.. It did send the image but it sends one exact image that was added last I think, doesn't matter on which CardView I click..
I need it to get the Image of the exact CardView that was clicked and send it as a bitmap I guess

Comment: So I need to get the Image from the String I made at the code at my main Post.. The String name is image_data (It stores and changes the ImageView basically..)

Comment: Seems like you should be fine. If my code helped, set it as the answer, so others see that this problem was dealt with. Thank you